# Scheduling Sequential Services

Tags: android, android-service, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

Is there any way within Android to schedule sequential services, similar to [sending ordered broadcasts](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#sendOrderedBroadcast) for `BroadcastReceivers`? What I mean is that I'm looking for something where I can start service A. Once service A completes, start service B. However, this gets a little more complicated because service A won't always need to be started, only sometimes.

More specifically, I have an activity that allows users to search for content. In order for me to make an HTML request (using Retrofit) once the user enters a query, I need to supply an access token. The access token is only valid for an hour. However, if a user makes another search request within that hour, there's no need for a new access token. Here's a quick logic diagram:

[image]

I've looked at `JobScheduler` and `JobDispatcher`, as well as [Android-Job from Evernote](https://evernote.github.io/android-job/). However, they all appear to do the same great things: start services when certain constraints are met. However, I couldn't find anything about handling *multiple* requests, specifically where one request is dependent on another.

Would anyone be able to provide some insight into this? I've thought about doing this with `BroadcastReceivers` as well, but couldn't think of anything that'd be a robust solution. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you checked WorkManager API(part of JetPack), using that you can create chain of jobs - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you wouldn't just have service A conditionally schedule (or just start) service B according to whatever logic it wants.

Or, factor the work the services perform into some other abstraction, and conditionally link them all within the context of a single service.

Comment: I could do what you're recommending. However, I was wondering if there's already something out there that handles my issue. I was hoping to make use of one of the scheduling frameworks offered within Android to play around with them (`JobScheduler` etc.). I understand if it's not practical to use them for my case though.

Comment: It's not clear to me what that other something would do, if it existed. You still need to write the logic for "goto next" somewhere. I guess you are looking for some declarative non-code way to chain together work elements? It'd need to be extremely general to allow for arbitrary "goto next, or not" logic in that framework.